# Premature end of script headers: index.php on Magento i cant find the solution

Tags: magento

Im getting 500 Internal Server Error on Magento site.

I read the Logs and find this..

```
Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

I dont make any changes, it only happens i dont know why.

I try all the solution found on Internet and cant make it work again, the Admin Work, but the web when try to load the index.php dont work.

This is wat i try:

- I put to all files on /magento/ to 644 and selected all directories var, app, media, js... and put 755.
- Restart httpd
- Check the suPHP Log if exced 2gb and is 0.
- Try removing htaccess
- RLimitMem 128000000 128000000 on htaccess and give me this error "Must be uid 0 to raise maximum RLimitMEM"
- Comment out this on htaccess Options +FollowSymLinks
- if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'myip') { Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); }

  Those errors was giving all the time but the web works great.
- I search for RLimitCPU and RLimitMEM directives on httpd.conf and dont find them.
- The memory limit is 126MB and some people told to increase the 32MB but i already increased it before. Now im trying with 256MB and dont work.
- Deleting umask(0); from index.php dont work.
- Trying with another Explorer dont work (because i read another post that with Firefox works the web but with chrome dont work, in my case dont work with any explorer)
- Adding AddType x-mapp-php5 .php to httaccess and get this error "[warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'"

I appreciate any help to fix this problem

Comment: Do you have any code after your ending `?>` tag in your php file?

Comment: Which php file you reffered? index.php? There is no ?>

Comment: Do you have any php tags in there?  Did you inadvertently add any HTML, text, or anything else that is not php after a php start tag?

Comment: I fix it deleting the System Logs, is bigger than 2GB.

Comment: Have you also delete the system log or error log or access log from cpanel i am facing same problem